# Unable to create a Team programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have successfully created Office 365 Group, added members and owners and now I am trying to provision a Team for this group. How am I supposed to provision it using MS Graph in .NET Console App?

I tried the following code but I am not getting my Team.

```
var team = new Team
{
    GuestSettings = new TeamGuestSettings
    {
        AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false,
        AllowDeleteChannels = false
    }
};

await graphServiceClient.Groups[groupID].Team.Request().CreateAsync(team);
```

Response from the above code

Message: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://api.teams.skype.com/v1.0/groups('da87fc59-403b-4b0f-973f-f812d41143aa')/team'.

Inner error

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SALkh.png)

Edit: I am using latest NUGET package for MS Graph extensions.

Edit 2: Tried to do following instead.

```
await graphServiceClient.Groups[groupID].Team.Request().PutAsync(team);
```

Got this:

Code: UnauthorizedAccess
Message: Failed to execute Aad backend request GetTenantSubscribedSkusRequest. Request Url: https://graph.windows.net/dc7b2a82-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-46122279d033/subscribedSkus?api-version=1.6, Request Method: GET, Response Status Code: Unauthorized, Response Headers: ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: HmmXXX+7Su9HNJVjwqsmVjPsrXXXXXXXX/iNwuI3H74=
request-id: 9257706c-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-bbf33b98da7d
client-request-id: f263695b-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-9fdf185fXXXX
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2019 13:20:18 GMT

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same `subscribedSkus` API error yesterday. The application worked before, then got the error, and after a couple of hours it was resolved again. Seems like an error happened in the backend for a while...

Comment: just tried now and still having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a service bug. Works now.

[Link to service bug on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/491)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft document says

> If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for
> the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication
> delays. The recommended pattern is to retry the Create team call three
> times, with a 10 second delay between calls.

I faced this issue and after the retry logic as suggested above it works fine all the time

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but back in the day ~Jul 16 2019 there was a service bug, see the marked answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you are using a **Delegated** authentication context (a user must be signed in) with the permission **Group.ReadWrite.All**
- Make sure you have **consented** to the application permissions (from the API permissions screen of the application registration, you'll find a `Grant Consent` button all the way down)
- Use the **PutAsync** method (today, as you mentioned, you must create the Office 365 group first and then enable Teams)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, currently I am using just Application Delegation, is it necessary to have the User token for this? I want that to be created by the "system" not user.

Comment: support for application permissions on Teams APIs is fairly new. And there is a notion of "belonging to a team/group" involved for some operations as documented here, which I'm not sure how it plays with app permissions. I was suggesting to try with a delegated scenario to see if it makes a difference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the group actually gets created? "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI" often means that the graphServiceClient.Groups[groupID] doesn't work. Which is likely around permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Group is definitely created, checked in AAD and even the members and owners are present, as baywet suggested, I might need to involve user token for this, although I wanted this app to work just as Application Delegation without involving any user account.

Comment: good point from Jeremy. Groups "take time to be available" and that might translate in 404's, 403's for some operations that should work during the first few minutes of their existence as documented here. You should probably implement some retry and wait logic to see if that improves the situation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I have read the ms documentation and tried after 40 mins from creation, still got the same issue, just got back to the office and will try in a bit. :-)

Comment: Even after a day it says still the same, will try to implement user Delegation tomorrow, but that kinda makes my plan useless. Can't understand why I am able to create group assign members edit sharepoint lists and not able to supply a team for a group :(

Comment: can you ensure that you have an owner and a member in the group when you create it in that call. i distinctly remember some requirement around that.

Comment: also have you tried for the sake of it adding some settings in both properties you pass through? rather than leaving empty.

Comment: The group exists, it has a owner, it has members, tried to fill it with the settings, same result... going to try with the User Delegation now

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I have the same problem with application permissions. The one thing I have found that will unblock the code to work again is to create a team through the Graph Explorer and then I am good for a couple days.

Then the error comes back again and I create another team through the explorer and I can start creating like before. This tells me it is not a code problem but an issue on the Teams graph connection somewhere.

Comment: Hello Ryan, thanks for your input. Tried to create the Team with Graph Explorer site, it got created, but still would not let me to create via code :-( did you advanced in this matter?